# Changing references to deprecated methods C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, refactoring, deprecated, automated-refactoring

I have some methods that are deprecated in my codebase and I know how I'm supposed to replace them, is there any way to do this automatically? I'm using Visual studio 2015 update 3 but I'm open to using other text editors...

The code looks like this :

```
// Deprecated method
myFunction(char* firstParam, char* secondParam = NULL);

// New method, same name, different params
myFunction(char* firstParam, bool flag, char* secondParam = NULL);
```

I just want something that could replace all references to the first function with a reference to the second one.
i.e:

```
myFunction( "hello", "world");
// Replace with
myFunction( "hello", true, "world");
```

and

```
myFunction("hello");
// Replace with
myFunction("hello", true);
```

and

```
myFunction("hello", isTrue); // isTrue is a bool here
// Do not replace with anything
```

and

```
myFunction("hello", world); //world is a char* here
// Replace with
myFunction("hello", true, world);
```

I'm open to solutions using visual studio or even other text editors. The reason I'm not doing it manually is because codebase is too large.

Comment: use the search & replace function of your editor? Not sure if I understand the question

Comment: I am not sure if I understand either because these are distinctly different methods with different signatures. You will not only have to modify the signatures, but in every place where you call the original method, you will need to update the code to support the new signature.

Comment: Like using a regex? because it's hard to catch the variable types using regex. (Or maybe I just don't know how)

Comment: Have the old function just call the new function? And use an [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) to mark the old function as `[[deprecated]]` (so the compiler can warn about its usage and help you find the calls)?

Comment: The idea is that the old functions are going to be erased at some point, not just have them deprecated. So I can't just say "myFunction("Hello", true);" in the deprecated function implementation.

Comment: That's basically what deprecation *means*, that something should be avoided because it might be removed in the future. With the attribute the compiler should add a warning whenever the deprecated function is called, and help the users of that function to find those locations and replace the calls before the old function is removed. If it's some kind of public API then it should also be mentioned in the documentation that the function will be removed by this version or by that date. That information could also be included in the reason of the deprecation attribute.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I'm asking for a way to replace my old function calls with new ones, because there are too many warnings and I don't want to do all of them manually, I'm asking for a effective way to replace deprecated methods with new ones

Comment: And for that, the only possible answer is the search-replace functionality in your editor.

Comment: You might implement the replacement automatically with clang-tidy.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

Change the old function to call the new with that argument being true (declare the new one above the old of course):

```
 // Deprecated method
 myFunction(char* firstParam, char* secondParam = NULL)
 {
     myFunction(firstParam, true, secondParam);
 }
```

You can probably inline it too so the compiler will literally change the code for you where appropriate :)

Comment: I like this answer, but the deprecated methods are going to be deleted at some point and then this will no longer work

Comment: @MichelJiang this would remove the old method since you would have replaced it. but like suggested above you could add the [[deprecated]] or in MSDEV __declspec(deprecated) marker on it to warn at compile time where code uses the old way, and replace as you go.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might be explaining myself badly in the question, but I want to avoid replacing the functions manually, my compiler already warns me about the fact that the functions are deprecated and that I should change them, I'm more looking for a way to replace them in code automatically :) But I will try what you suggest and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=StackOverflow), using [DMS's source-to-source transformations](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewriteRules.html?site=StackOverflow).

DMS parses (C++17/VisualStudio2015) source code to an AST, applies the source-to-source transforms which modify the tree, and the the result AST is prettyprinted to regenerate (modified) source code.  This allows one to automate code changes across large code bases in a reliable way.

DMS rewrite rules for OP's examples would look like this:

```
rule add_true_to_hello_world()
    :functioncall->functioncall
    = "myFunction( \"hello\", \"world\");"
    -> "myFunction( \"hello\", true, \"world\");";

rule add_true_to_call_with_literal_string(s: STRING)
    : functioncall->functioncall
    = "myFunction(\s)"
    -> "myFunction(\s, true);"

rule add_true_when_char_star(i:IDENTIFIER,s:STRING, a:argument):
     :functioncall->functioncall
     = "\i(\s,\a);"
     -> "\i(\s, true, \a)"
     if IsCharStart(a);

ruleset replace_deprecated_calls =
    { add_true_to_hello_world,
      add_true_to_call_with_literal_string,
      add_true_when_char_star
    }
```

Breif explanation: rules have the form

```
rule name(metavariable): syntaxclass->syntaxclass
  lefthandside -> righthandside  if condition ;
```

Rules have names so people and rulesets can refer to them conveniently; sometimes one might have thousands of rules to carry out very complex transforms.  A rule has parameters specifying what kind of metavariables (written \v) are allowed inside the rule.  The "functioncall->functioncall" notation means we are transforming function calls into function calls and not something else.  Quote marks around C++ text are *meta*quotes delimiting C++ text from DMS rule text, causing us to need to escape the actual C++ literal string quote marks with \". [Yeah we might have designed DMS to make that case non-escaped; can't always be clever enough].

A ruleset just groups rules to they can all be applied as a group.  Not shown is the trivial DMS call to apply the ruleset.

You can read more about rule syntax at the link above.

I implemented his rules differently than OP expressed.  His examples show only a function call as a statement (note the ";" in his examples) getting changed, but he writes in the text that he wants to replace all function calls.  Thus these rules are about changes to function calls, not statements.  OP's first rule I coded exactly as he showed in his example; it will only work if the function call has literally those argument string literas.  His second rule I generalized to allow an arbitrary literal string rather than just "world".  The third rule I generalized to allow an arbitrary function name and added a type check as he indicated.

Note the pattern matches actually occur over syntax trees and not raw text.  DMS won't be fooled by function calls inside comments or with different whitespacing/formatting.

Answer (score -1):

What about using "Edit | Find & replace | Replace in Files" ?
Replace *"Hello", world* with *"Hello", true, world*

Comment: This wouldn't work for the case where it's using the new function signature already...

Comment: I will add it will not work if other object who  could have similar function names too.. It is better to use an IDE that has a refactor functionality where it will only match the symbols that do compile to be that function call with or without the optional/defaulted argument.